# iOS Multiple views/labels with different width

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, swift2

I want to create `5 UILabel` with different **width** using **autolayout**, I don't know how to set constraints for this. I want to create the view like following

[image]

It should resize automatically with the same ratio **(Label 5 & Label 2 should have more width than other Labels)** on all devices (iPhone and iPad). Can anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: If you can think of each labels width in terms of a % of the width of the superview then you could set it up that way.

Comment: do you want it such that label2 and label5 have same width which is 2 times the width of all the other labels and label 1,3,4 have same width

Comment: How did you achieve this? Did you get any solution for it? I also want to know solution for it. I am facing same issues with Views. Glad if you help me

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can set an aspect ratio constraint between the labels.</s>

If you're using the interface builder, you can do this by right clicking a label and dragging to the other label, this will show a menu with the aspect ratio option

You can use an equal widths constraint with a multiplier, which will keep the ratio between the widths

If you're using the interface builder, you can do this by right clicking a label and dragging to the other label, this will show a menu with the equal widths option

Comment: It is <kbd>Control</kbd>+"Click and Drag to other element"

Comment: Right click drag has the same effect

Comment: Doesn't aspect ratio refer to the ratio between height and width of a single element?

Comment: @MikePollard, yes i'm thinking the same

Comment: @MikePollard you're right, it has to be equal widths with a multiplier, thanks for the correction

Comment: Yes. I'd go for anchoring all the edges together appropriately with label1 anchored to the left superview edge and label5 the right, then add on width constraints for each label = x% of width of the superview.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved on various ways. The one I think you are looking for is [content hugging resistance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/contentHuggingPriorityForAxis:) and [compression resistance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forAxis:). You can set how much it should resist from stretching and/or hugging. So in your case you set same values of this for label 2 and 5 and other for rest.

With VFL I would go with something like this:

```
H:|[label1][label2(>=label5)][label3][label4][label5]|
```

and for label 2 and 5 I would set the hugging priority to low and for others I would set it as high. that would keep 2 and 5 taking the left space and restrict others from growing overt it really needs to. This is what I can advice looking at the info you provided.

Comment: i tried that. but can you explain me little bit. It's somewhere conflicting with my superview and if i resolve it by changing priority. It's asking me to create width constraint

Comment: I could be helpful here but I need to know where and how you want to set it with information of other views :)

Comment: I'm keeping all the label inside one view. I want label 5 which is slight bigger than other labels and label 2 should be bigger than label 5

Comment: edited my answer see it that is fine in your case, if we set that label2 has to be at lest same width as 5 then we do not need to mess around its content hugging

Comment: or if you want to be more precise you can set the width of label2 to be like 105% (for example) of label 5